Setting up Python and Jupyter on home PC, tried opening Jupyter notebook and states Error, Failed to fetch
I have the latest Python version of 3.12.4 and the below version of Jupyter:
Selected Jupyter core packages...IPython          : 8.26.0ipykernel        : 6.29.5ipywidgets       : not installedjupyter_client   : 8.6.2jupyter_core     : 5.7.2jupyter_server   : 2.14.2jupyterlab       : 4.2.4nbclient         : 0.10.0nbconvert        : 7.16.4nbformat         : 5.10.4notebook         : 7.2.1qtconsole        : not installedtraitlets        : 5.14.3

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong to start up a notebook to work and practice Python as well as try to create programs for automation as I want to clean up a massive gmail account. Would appreciate a rundown on how to operate Python and Jupyter as I have also had to install Anaconda3.
When I first installed all the programs, I used to go from my Terminal and would type jupyter notebook and it would bring me to Google Chrome where I was able to set up my notebook: FirstNotebook.ipynb
It had me set a kernel and then I came back to trying to open the notebook a day later and I get the error of Failed to Fetch and now I don't know where to go to set an environment to work with for Python as I also want to set up Quarto in the Jupyter notebook. Any help will be much appreciated.
